# How do I convert a UITextField to an integer in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, integer

I'm a beginner at swift, and was doing some testing. To tell you the truth, I barely know what I'm doing yet, so please try to explain clearly. I was making a random number generator app & wanted to add in a `uitextfield` so that the user can type in their guess of the next randomly generated number. I keep getting an error when trying to use the if statement to compare the randomly generated number to the number entered In the text field.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField! 
    @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel! // Displayed Before The User Clicks Button For The First Time.
    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func go(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Remove The Text Under The Button 
        infoLabel.text = " "

        // Generate Random Number 
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(11))

        // Change The "Number Label's" Text In Order To Show The Randomly Generated Number To The User        
        numberLabel.text = "\(randomNumber)"

        // Check To See If The User Guessed The Correct Number, And If They Did, Tell Them They Were Right
        if input == randomNumber {
            infoLabel.text = "Your Guess,\(randomNumber) Was Correct!"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: What do U expect to have when U compare UITextField type with Int type ? Correct it to `if([input.text intValue] == randomNumber)` //Obj-C syntax

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To convert the input string to an integer using Swift 2:

```
let guess:Int? = Int(input.text)

if guess == randomNumber { 
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH!!! I had to just put an exclamation point after input.text, but after that it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

To access it's int value:

```
Int(input.text)
```

The input variable has type UITextField, which is an object and can't be compared to an Int. So you have to access its text, which is an string, and cannot be compared to Int as well, so, convert it to an Int using the expression above, it will give you the int value that the string holds.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this, can you explain why? I don't see anything wrong with his answer.

Comment: @nick Perhaps because the question is asking about Swift 2, in which `toInt()` has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert string into int using this:

**input.text.toInt()!**

Comment: No, not in Swift 2 - this is for Swift 1.

Answer (score -1):

in Swift 3 
you should compare equivalent number type: for example convert string to int.

```
let guess = Int(input.text!)! 
if guess == randomNumber {your code}
```